# Blurred Font/Color - Wine

Tags: linux, fonts, wine

Why do I get this strange blurred fonts after installing a software running the lasted **wine-5.11** on Arch Linux 5.7.6.

I installed all fonts listed in **Winetricks->Install a font** and they are correctly listed in **`Winetricks->Regedit->HKEY_CURRENT_USER->Software->Fonts->External Fonts`**.

[image: Text]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the trick for that font smoothing rendering bug:

## Enable font smoothing

A good way to improve wine font rendering is to enable cleartype font smoothing. To enable "Subpixel smoothing (ClearType) RGB":

```
cat << EOF > /tmp/fontsmoothing
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothing"="2"
"FontSmoothingOrientation"=dword:00000001
"FontSmoothingType"=dword:00000002
"FontSmoothingGamma"=dword:00000578
EOF

WINE=${WINE:-wine} WINEPREFIX=${WINEPREFIX:-$HOME/.wine} $WINE regedit /tmp/fontsmoothing 2> /dev/null
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wine#Enable_font_smoothing